# авторизация spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

Каким образом будет правильнее организовать авторизацию в spring приложении?
Имеется приложение, в котором есть контроллер с страницей регистрации, которая при заполнении формы передает данные в базу данных(postgresql) данные в колонки login, password, email и userrole. Я хочу создать форму логина, с помощью которой пользователь мог бы авторизоваться, а также чтобы после регистрации/авторизации пользователь не мог просто перейдя по адресу со страницей регистрации иметь возможность зарегистрироваться снова, пока не произведет логаут. Каким способом в такой ситуации лучше воспользоваться в spring security? JWT-токен? И как сама проверка должна выглядеть, учитывая, что я не разделяю юзера и возможные роли на несколько баз данных?

Comment: Думаю, важно добавить, что у меня всего две роли - юзер и админ, при этом админ всего один, и он уже имеется в базе. Исходя из этого, при создании пользователя, ему автоматически назначается роль юзера.

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце на этот вопрос ответить сложно, все зависит от ваших пожеланий.
Довольно много мануалов на эту тему. Есть достаточно простой вариант для Ваших потребностей с использованием OAuth 2.0.
Прикрепляю неплохие уроки на эту тему.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDlifgLS8iQ&list=PLU2ftbIeotGoGSEUf54LQH-DgiQPF2XRO&index=3

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ohlXEJeRX8&list=PLU2ftbIeotGqSTOVNjT4L3Yfy8jatCdhm&index=5

Comment: сейчас немного разобрался, правда столкнулся с немного другой проблемой. За уроки спасибо!